# Is there a way to get an specific object which is inside an array without typing array[somenumber]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongoose, axios

I'm working with MongoDB using Mongoose and making GET calls with Axios from the client to the server.

So... I'm making this call with Axios

```
axios.get(route).then(res => {
            const races = res.data[0].InsideRaceResults

            console.log(races)
})

/* AND I LOG THIS

(17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716eed", gpId: "Austrian Grand Prix", grandPrixDate: "Sunday, July 5", grandPrixTrack: "Red Bull Ring", RaceResult: Array(20)}
1: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716f02", gpId: "Styrian Grand Prix", grandPrixDate: "Sunday, July 12", grandPrixTrack: "Red Bull Ring", RaceResult: Array(20)}

...

*/
```

So, if I wanted to enter inside the first element of that array, obviusly I would type [0], and if I want to enter inside the second element I would go with [1].

What I want to do is something similar to this mongoose query.

```
StandingsModel.updateOne({ "_id": "2020 Standings" },
        {
            '$set': { 'InsideRaceResults.$[race].RaceResult.$[result].driverName': 'Lewis Hamilton' },
        }, {
        "arrayFilters": [
            { "race._id": fatherid },
            { "result._id": childid }]
})
```

Where with arrayFilters I can get the object which is inside the array that matches with the value that the user typed.

But, is there a way to do something similar to that with JS in order to get this...?

```
//This is what I tought that could be a good approach but obviusly it wasn't.

axios.get(route).then(res => {
            const races = res.data[0].InsideRaceResults[{gpId: "Styrian Grand Prix"}]

            console.log(races)
})

/* What I want to log

{_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716f02", gpId: "Styrian Grand Prix", grandPrixDate: "Sunday, July 12", grandPrixTrack: "Red Bull Ring", RaceResult: Array(20)}

*/
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: Also, you should use TypeScript for this. Otherwise you'll run into problems as your project scales (e.g. how is `res.data` defined?)

Comment: Thanks Dai, oh, I must read that docs. I'm new so I would try to explain it as I understand. In my server I got a route with a Json that contains the data that I'm using in the client side (getting it with Axios). That json is just a collection from MongoDB that I call with the query model.find().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` (and `Array.prototype.map`):

```
const races    = res.data[0].InsideRaceResults;
const filtered = races.filter( r => r.gpId === "Styrian Grand Prix" ); // Note that `filter` returns an array.
if( filtered.length === 0 ) {
    // no results.
} else if( filtered.length === 1 ) {
    // exactly 1 match.
} else {
    // multiple matches.
}
```

You'll need to decide how to handle the 3 different result `filtered` cases.